# domain configuration in docker-compose

Tags: docker, dns, docker-compose

How to configure hostnames with domains in `docker-compose.yml`?

Let's say the service `worker` expects the service `web` on the `http://web.local/` address.  But `web.local` doesn't resolve to an ip address no matter what I configure using the `hostname` directive. Adding an `extra_hosts` directive doesn't work either as I should know the ip of the service `web` for that, which I don't as it is assigned by docker.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  worker:
    build: ./worker
    networks:
      - mynet    
  web:
    build: ./web
    ports:
      - 80:80
    hostname: web.local
    networks:
      - mynet
networks:
  mynet:
```

but `ping web.local` doesn't resolve inside the service `worker`

Comment: Are you trying to ping the "web.local" from your "worker" container or from your host?

Comment: I want to ping it from my worker. (I want to issue http requests from my worker, to be more specific, but it fails at ip resolution.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For this to work you need to add an `alias` in the network `mynet`.

From the [official](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks) documentation:

> Aliases (alternative hostnames) for this service on the network. Other
>   containers on the same network can use either the service name or this
>   alias to connect to one of the service’s containers.

So, your `docker-compose.yml` file should look like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  worker:
    build: ./worker
    networks:
      - mynet  
  web:
    build: ./web
    ports:
      - 80:80
    hostname: web.local
    networks:
       mynet:    
          aliases:
            - web.local
networks:
  mynet:
```

Comment: Hi, I have a PostgreSQL container and a web server. According to this example, my db is `web` here and my server is `worker` ?

Comment: @SleebaPaul can you give me more details? or create a new question with all the details and I will answer it

Comment: Okay I've a PostgreSQL container, and a Swift server container. I need to pass the db ip to the Server to start it. So I created an alias for db in my custom bridge network. But when I do that, the error says, `message: "could not translate host name \"mynetworkdb\" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution\n"`

Comment: @SleebaPaul give me your `docker-compose.yml` file

Comment: I've added a question. Find it here. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54324599/docker-container-communication-could-not-translate-host-name-somealias-to