# Docker container communication - "Could not translate host name \"mydbalias\" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops

I have a PostgreSQL container and a Swift server container. I need to pass the DB IP to the Server to start it. So I created an alias for DB in my custom bridge network. Have a look at my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
    db:
      build: database
      image: postgres
      networks:
        mybridgenet:
          aliases:
            - mydbalias
    web:
      image: mywebserver:latest
      ports: 
        - "8000:8000"
      depends_on: 
        - db
      networks:
        - mybridgenet
      environment:
        WAIT_HOSTS: db:5432

networks:
  mybridgenet:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile to build webserver.

```
FROM swift:4.2.1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y libpq-dev uuid-dev  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
EXPOSE 8000
WORKDIR /app

COPY client ./client
COPY Package.swift ./
COPY Package.resolved ./

COPY Sources ./Sources
RUN swift build

COPY pkg-swift-deps.sh ./
RUN chmod +x ./pkg-swift-deps.sh
RUN ./pkg-swift-deps.sh ./.build/debug/bridgeOS

FROM busybox:glibc

COPY --from=0 /app/swift_libs.tar.gz /tmp/swift_libs.tar.gz
COPY --from=0 /app/.build/debug/bridgeOS /usr/bin/

RUN tar -xzvf /tmp/swift_libs.tar.gz && \
    rm -rf /tmp/*

ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.2.1/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait

CMD /wait && mywebserver db "10.0.2.2"
```

Database Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres

COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

The server is started using `mybinary mydbalias`. Like I said earlier, I pass the alias to start the server. While doing this, I get the following error.

`message: "could not translate host name \"mydbalias\" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution\n"`

What could be the problem?

---

**UPDATE**

After 4 days of a grueling raid, I finally found the rat. He is  `busybox` container. I changed it to `ubuntu:16.04` and it's a breeze. Feeling so good about this whole conundrum. Thanks, everyone who helped.

Comment: Does it work if you remove `driver: bridge` ?

Comment: Just tried it. No luck.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu I've added used a multi stage build Dockerfile for building the Swift app. You can find it's details here. https://medium.com/@jjacobson/a-minimal-swift-docker-image-b93d2bc1ce3c

Comment: `I need to pass the DB IP to the Server to start it` - what do you mean by "start it"? you don't "start it" but "connect to it"

Comment: In the start script of my server container, I need to pass the hostname such that, the server will first connect to the DB and then launch the server.

Comment: Are you using `docker-compose up` or `docker stack deploy` to start the containers/services?

Comment: I use `docker compose up` after building the server using `docker build -t mywebserver:latest --no-cache .`

Comment: I updated the question with Dockerfiles content. Please have a look.

Comment: `CMD /wait && mywebserver db "10.0.2.2"` -- what is this ip?

Comment: My container lives in a virtual box installed in a windows host. To communicate with the windows host, that IP is used.

Comment: Do you still have message `could not translate host name \"db\" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution\n` or it has changed to another?

Comment: Same error! Kind of stuck on this for last 3 days :(

Answer (score 1):

Simplify. There is no need in your explicit network declaration (it is done automatically by `docker-compose`, nor aliases (services get their host names based on service names)

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
    db:
      build: database
      image: postgres
    web:
      image: mywebserver:latest
      ports: 
        - "8000:8000"
      depends_on: 
        - db
      environment:
        WAIT_HOSTS: db:5432
```

Then just use `db` as a hostname to connect to database from `web`

Comment: Tried it now. No luck.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu I've added used a multi stage build Dockerfile for building the Swift app. You can find it's details here. medium.com/@jjacobson/a-minimal-swift-docker-image-b93d2bc1ce3c

`PostgresSessionConnector.host = HOST_NAME`
 `let sessionDriver = SessionPostgresDriver()`
`connection = try myOSDB()`
 
is the swift code.

Comment: So what is `HOST_NAME` ??

Comment: As you directed, I gave it `db`

Comment: Okay, and why there is `build` option in yaml for your `db` service? Isnt `postgres` available as ready image? What are you overriding in it?

Comment: There is an `init.sql` needs to be executed. I take it from a database Dockerfile

Comment: That looks like you have problems in your database image. Probably if you stated your `Dockerfile` it could be easier to understand

Comment: I updated the question with Dockerfiles content. Please have a look.